# What is the naming convention of NodeJS?

Tags: node.js, naming-conventions

I found that the naming conversion of node is a little strange. For instance, in the [file system module](http://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_file_system), the [read link function](http://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readlink_path_callback)'s letters are all lower cased:

```
fs.readlink
```

But the [read file function](http://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readfile_filename_options_callback)'s name are camelized:

```
fs.readFile
```

It confused me. After mistyping for times, I think I shoud ask. So is there a naming convention to help me memorize the api names?

Comment: Don't forget the inconsistently named `fs.readdir`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Node's default convention is camelCase.
But functions in file system module named according to their respective POSIX C interface functions.
For example [readdir](http://linux.die.net/man/3/readdir), [readlink](http://linux.die.net/man/3/readdir).
These functions names are well-known by Linux developers and therefore it's often decided to use them as is(as single word), without camelizing.

Answer (score 1):

Always go camel case, almostly everyone does it.

The Node core does have various disparities in this case, like the one you mentioned, [process](http://nodejs.org/api/process.html) have some too (`process.get*()` x `process.memoryUsage()`), and others; but [the majority of the core methods](http://nodejs.org/api/all.html) are camel cased.
Until you memorize the ones who are not camel cased, I'd say that it's a good tip to always develop with the docs open ;)